# Images not displaying in Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-urls, django-media

In Django 1.8, I can upload images and they are saved on the path that they should, but when I add the path to template, the images are not displaying. I GET 200 http code for them in terminal server.

Here are the relevant parts in settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And in urls.py I have added:

```
urlpatterns = [
...

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Example image tag path:

```
<img src="/media/photos/1/1430598029_08_ranaplazaslide.jpg" />
```

and the Get code:

```
GET /media/photos/1/1430598029_08_ranaplazaslide.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 20888
```

I am wondering what is wrong with my settings and how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your settings.  200 is an OK http code so your server doing it right.  Open the `/media/photos/1/1430598029_08_ranaplazaslide.jpg` with you browser and image will be shown.

Comment: What happens when you open the image url on the browser?

Comment: @DigitalDouble when I open the image path, the default page appears, instead of the image.

Comment: Update your question with the full code of your `urls.py`. Seems like you have invalid regex for home page.

Comment: @catavaran you are right. When I comment out the last line in urls.py, which is `url(r'^', 'article.views.main'),` the image appears. Please answer and I'll accpet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `$` sign to the regex for your home page:

```
url(r'^$', 'article.views.main')
```